# MongoDB, Is there a method that can add a new field before when updating a document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new in mongodb, about updating a document, i'm asking if there is a method on mongo to add a new field before or after an existing field, here is a simple exemple:

```
{"_id":'a1', name: 'joe doe', age: 32 }
```

in this document, i want to update by setting up an email field before the age field like this:

```
{"_id":'a1', name: 'joe doe', email: 'joedoe@test.test', age: 32 }
```

Comment: the solution posed @k0ner is the closest to what I want, thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have such order as you posted then you need to store the value of `db.collection.find(...)` and use

```
db.collection.update({ filter }, {name: stored.name, email: 'joedoe@test.test', age: stored.age })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method and the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator.

```
db.collection.update({/*your filter*/}, { '$set': { 'email': 'joedoe@test.test' } } )
```

This will not reorder your fields the "email" field will be after the "age" because as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-field-order):

> Starting in version 2.6, MongoDB actively attempts to preserve the field order in a document. Before version 2.6, MongoDB did not actively preserve the order of the fields in a document.

so you newly updated document will look like this:

```
{ "_id" : "a1", "name" : "joe doe", "age" : 32, "email" : "joedoe@test.test" }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is an object so the order does not matter. If you want to keep a specific order you should use an array i.e.

```js
{"_id":'a1', data : [{name: 'joe doe'}, {age: 32}] }
```

Then you can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) operator and specify its [$position](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position) in an array like that:

```js
db.collection.update({"_id":"a1"}, {
  $push: {
    data: {
       $each: [ {"email":"joedoe@test.test"} ],
       $position: 1
    }
  }
});
```

It will result in a document that has an object {email: 'joedoe@test.test} on a position number 1 in its "data" array:

```js
{"_id":'a1', data : [{name: 'joe doe'}, {email: 'joedoe@test.test'}, {age: 32}] }
```